# Tomcat SSL error

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

I am getting the following error on tomcat startup in the logs. I am using tomcat 7 and ubuntu.

```
java.io.IOException: SSL configuration is invalid due to No available certificate or key     corresponds to the SSL cipher suites which are enabled.
```

I am using the following link to import the certificate

https://support.comodo.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=1204&nav=0,128,96,1,95

Are there any additional steps that i have to follow or missing?

I had generated the CSR and provided to the provider and they provided me the Certificate files.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that you have configured your keystore with your certificates in the server.xml config file for Tomcat (located at /conf/server.xml).

The line should look something like this:

```
<Connector
       protocol="HTTP/1.1"
       port="8443" maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       keystoreFile="/path/to/keystore.keystore" keystorePass="<keystorepassword>"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

If you have already done this, it is possible the certificate you generated does not use ciphers that Tomcat considers secure. You may need to regenerate your certificates with more secure ciphers, or configure Tomcat to allow more cipher types.

More information on setting up Tomcat with SSL is available in the Tomcat documentation here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Quick_Start

Comment: VG but certificates don't use ciphers. They use key types and key lengths. I doubt that Tomcat puts any restrictions on those.

Comment: I have added the mentioned code in server.xml but i am still getting the error.

Comment: If there is a signature on the private key associated with the certificate, it uses a certain type of cipher for the signature. It is possible it could  put a restriction on that if it were using something less secure, such as MD5.